# Is there any difference if we apply multiple conditions within for loop rather than giving it in loop body with if else

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a result array res[3 2 3 5 5 6 0 8 9 0 ] and if the value is not zero then I want to subtract each element with its index. If have written like this

```
for(int i=0;i<res.length && res[i]!=0;i++)
res[i] =res[i]-i;
```

this gives an Output res[3,1,1,2,1,1,0,8,9,0]

but when I write like

```
for(int i=0;i<res.length;i++){
  if(res[i]!=0)
  res[i] =res[i]-i; }
```

It gives o/p as [3,1,1,2,1,1,0,1,1,0]

I don't understand why the condition within the loop is behaving differently than in IF condition in its body.??

Comment: For first case, the for loop will terminate when `res[i]==0`, while second case will not.

Answer (score 3):

In the first scenario, the middle statement defines the execution of the code block (here, when to exit your for-loop). So, when your condition fails (6th index), the loop is exited without running further iterations.

In the second scenario, the condition for exiting the for-loop is that the value of the iterator is less than the array size. As long as the loop does not fail, the code block within the loop is executed for all iterations.

Answer (score 0):

In first snippet code , loop check every time condition before the executing for each element, if condition fullful than its execute the code for element otherwise its terminate the loop execution for remaining element/elements.

where as in second snippet code, loop is executing for all the elements as loop check condition for all the elements than for each element you are checking the condition.

second code snippet is correct for requirement.